# Is it possible to create a fixed-length array property

Tags: arrays, vb.net, properties

I have a situation where I need to create a DTO class which stores a list of sub-items, but the number of sub-items in the list needs to be fixed.  Since it's a DTO, I need to be able to modify the value of each item in the list, but I don't want the consuming code to be able to add or remove items from the list.

For an example, lets say that I need a `Person` class, and I need that `Person` class to store a list of phone numbers.  For the sake of the example, lets just say that a person can only ever have three phone numbers.  In any other language, I'd just create the list as an array, since arrays in other languages cannot be resized.  However, in VB.NET, you can always call `ReDim` on any array, even if you use the `VBFixedArray` attribute.  For instance, this does *not* do what I need:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim p As New Person()
    p.PhoneNumbers(0) = "555-555-5555"
    ReDim Preserve p.PhoneNumbers(5)  ' Successfuly changes the size of the array--not good
End Sub

Public Class Person
    <VBFixedArray(2)>
    Public PhoneNumbers As String() = {"", "", ""}
End Class
```

If I try to use `IReadOnlyList`, then the size becomes fixed, but so do the items themselves.  For instance, this won't work:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim p As New Person()
    p.PhoneNumbers(0) = "555-555-5555" ' Compile error: Property 'Item' is 'ReadOnly'.
End Sub

Public Class Person
    Public ReadOnly Property PhoneNumbers As IReadOnlyList(Of String)
        Get
            Return _phoneNumbers.AsReadOnly()
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _phoneNumbers As New List(Of String)({"", "", ""})
End Class
```

So, how can I, in VB.NET, make a public property on my DTO class, which contains a fixed-length list of items, where the value of the items can be changed, but the number of items cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that in VB.NET, all arrays are resizeable using `ReDim`, but that's actually an illusion.  The underlying MSIL does not actually support resizable arrays.  When you call `ReDim Preserve` on an array in VB.NET it doesn't resize the existing array--it actually creates a new array, copies the data from the old array to the new one, and then points your array variable to the new array.  Bear in mind that arrays in .NET are reference types.  For instance:

```
Dim test1() As String = {"1", "2", "3"}
Dim test2() As String = test1
test2(0) = "after"
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", test1))  ' Outputs "after, 2, 3"
```

Therefore, if you create a property for an array, the property-setter will get called whenever you use `ReDim` to resize the property's array.  For instance:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim p As New Person()
    ReDim p.PhoneNumbers(3)  ' Outputs "Setter called"
End Sub

Public Class Person
    Public Property PhoneNumbers As String()
        Get
            Return _phoneNumbers
        End Get
        Set(value As String())
            Console.WriteLine("Setter called")
            _phoneNumbers = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _phoneNumbers As String()
End Class
```

Therefore, if you want to create a fixed-length list, where the items can be changed, but the number of items cannot be altered, you can create a read-only property which returns an array, like this:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim p As New Person()
    p.PhoneNumbers(0) = "555-555-5555"  ' Works
    ReDim p.PhoneNumbers(5)  ' Compile error: Property 'PhoneNumbers' is 'ReadOnly'.
End Sub

Public Class Person
    Public ReadOnly Property PhoneNumbers As String()
        Get
            Return _phoneNumbers
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _phoneNumbers(2) As String
End Class
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to expose the list as an array, you can make the property return an `IList` like this:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim p As New Person()
    p.PhoneNumbers(0) = "555-555-5555"  ' Works
    Console.WriteLine(p.PhoneNumbers.IsReadOnly)  ' Outputs "True"
    p.PhoneNumbers.Add("555-555-5555")  ' Compiles, but throws a NotSupportedException: "Collection was of a fixed size."
End Sub

Public Class Person
    Public ReadOnly Property PhoneNumbers As IList(Of String)
        Get
            Return _phoneNumbers
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _phoneNumbers(2) As String
End Class
```

You would think that you could make the property return an `IReadOnlyList`, but if you do, that makes it so you cannot change the value of any of the items in the list (at least not without casting it), for instance:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim p As New Person()
    p.PhoneNumbers(0) = "555-555-5555"  ' Compile error: Property 'Item' is 'ReadOnly'.
End Sub

Public Class Person
    Public ReadOnly Property PhoneNumbers As IReadOnlyList(Of String)
        Get
            Return _phoneNumbers
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _phoneNumbers(2) As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option to consider is to make the PhoneNumbers Property parameterized (returning only a string instead of an array).  This forces the consuming code to get one Phone Number at a time, which may or may not be an issue for you.  I used List(of String) in this code example, but it could easily be adapted to use an array instead.

```
Public Class Person
    Private _lstPhones As New List(Of String)
    Private Const _intPhoneUpperBounds As Integer = 3

    Public Sub New()
        For intCursor As Integer = 0 To _intPhoneUpperBounds
            _lstPhones.Add(String.Empty)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Property Phones(ByVal intIndex As Integer) As String
        Get
            If _lstPhones.Count > intIndex Then
                Return _lstPhones(intIndex)
            Else
                'Or exception.
                Return String.Empty
            End If
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If intIndex < _intPhoneUpperBounds Then
                _lstPhones(intIndex) = value
            Else
                'Throw Exception
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  I try to avoid parameters on properties, since they aren't well supported by other languages, but it's a good point.  I guess the other down-side to this approach would be that the consuming code couldn't get the count without adding another property for that, though typically that would be a known constant, in these situations, anyway.  Thanks for the input +1